# Read Request Header from Dependency Injection Container .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, httpcontext

I've got some question about accessing HttpContext from DI Container for .NET Core (I am using .NET 6 to be specific). My purpose is to get request header e.g. CorrelationId. Here is my DI Container code.

```
        services.AddControllers()
                .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(o =>
                {
                    o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = c =>
                    {
                        var keys = c.ModelState.Where(l => l.Value.Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => k.Key).ToList();
                        string error = string.Empty;

                        if (keys != null)
                        {
                            error = keys.Count <= 1 ? keys[0] : keys[1];
                            error = error.Replace("$.", string.Empty);
                        }

                        error = $"Field: {error}. Message: {c.ModelState.Values.ElementAt(0).Errors[0].ErrorMessage}";
                        
                        //GET REQUEST HEADER
                        //string correlationId = retrieve correlationId from request header
                        Response response = new();
                        response.Fail(correlatinId, error);

                        return new BadRequestObjectResult(response);
                    };
                })
                .AddFluentValidation(o =>
                {
                    o.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
                    o.ImplicitlyValidateRootCollectionElements = true;
                    o.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<LogErrorValidation>();
                });
```

The purpose of my code snippet is to override Bad Request response model with custom response model since I am using Fluent Validation. My custom response model consist of *correlationId (GUID)* and *message (string)*.

Is it possible to retrieve request header from DI container?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I guess I miss something, it can be done with

```
services.AddControllers()
                .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(o =>
                {
                    o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = c =>
                    {
                        var keys = c.ModelState.Where(l => l.Value.Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => k.Key).ToList();
                        string error = string.Empty;

                        if (keys != null)
                        {
                            error = keys.Count <= 1 ? keys[0] : keys[1];
                            error = error.Replace("$.", string.Empty);
                        }
                        //Read HTTP Context from Action Context (in this case is c)
                        var correlationId = c.HttpContext?.Request?.Headers?["CorrelationId"].FirstOrDefault();
                        error = $"Field: {error}. Message: {c.ModelState.Values.ElementAt(0).Errors[0].ErrorMessage}";

                        Response response = new();
                        response.Fail(correlationId, error);

                        return new BadRequestObjectResult(response);
                    };
                })
                .AddFluentValidation(o =>
                {
                    o.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
                    o.ImplicitlyValidateRootCollectionElements = true;
                    o.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<LogErrorValidation>();
                });
```